# SignalR 2.1.2 Cannot call server method from client, but can call client from server

Tags: signalr

I'm not sure what is wrong here and it has to be something stupid simple. However I've checked over everything, tried several different things, all with no success.

The server to client communication works great. No problems.

But when I call `notifications.server.test();` I get nothing. Nada.

I can call my testFunction() from the server and it works. but calling the hub's Test() method (which just calls testFunction) gives me nothing.

Here is the hub:

```
 namespace XXXX.Hubs
{
    [HubName("monitoringHub")]
    public class MonitoringHub : Hub
    {
        [HubMethodName("sendCustomers")]
        public static void SendCustomers()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MonitoringHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateCustomers();
        }

        [HubMethodName("sendDetails")]
        public static void SendDetails(string SONumber)
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MonitoringHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateDetails(SONumber);
        }

        [HubMethodName("test")]
        public static void Test()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MonitoringHub>();
            context.Clients.All.testFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

And the client code:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/systemdetails.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.monitoringHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateDetails = function (sonumber) {
            getDetails(sonumber)
        };

        notifications.client.testFunction = function () {
            alert("Test Function");
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //alert("connection started")
            getDetails(@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString());

            setInterval(function (){
                alert("Test Call");
                notifications.server.test();
            }, 5000);

        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

    function getDetails(sonumber) {
        if(sonumber = (@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString())){
            var tbl = $('#systemDetails');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Monitoring/GetDetails/@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString()',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false
            }).success(function (result) {
                storeVis();
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).complete(function(){
                recallVis();
            }).error(function () {
            });
        }
    }
</script>
}
```

My interval function issues the alert as expected, It should then call the hub method which comes back and calls the testFunction to issue the second alert. I cannot get the second Alert to fire when I try to call the hub method from the client, but if I call the hub method (or the Clients.All.testFunction) on the server side, it works fine. What gives?

On the server side I have tried different formats to call the server hub, but as it is now is how it should be according to the documentation for the version I'm on.

`notifications.client.test()` No.
`notifications.test()` No.
`notifications.server.test()` No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client cannot see your functions as they are not part of the instance of the hub. They are static and therefore the SignalR hub serializer does not write them out to the hub's dynamic javascript file.

If you must have static functions for other classes to access, you'll need to add non-static functions to your hub class that call your static functions. Your client will then be able to access them.